# Determine if HTML broken file link request

Tags: php, html, apache, http

I've developed a PHP application where I've created a routing system using apache.
With this routing system, every http request is pointed to index.php except if the request is an actual file on the server.

My problem is that, if the file doesn't exist, all my whole application is executed for each time a file request delivers a 404 error, resulting in my application to become real slow.

I've tried to listen to the `$_SERVER` to see if I'd spot some data that would indicate me that the execution was made by a broken file link and if I found anything I would execute the `die()` function so the application isn't loaded.

I've didn't found anything on `$_SERVER` and neither with any of the functions bellow:

```
getallheaders();
headers_list();
headers_sent();
http_response_code();
```

Initially I was using the script bellow but then found out that if any one put a string like `somestring.test` at the end of the request, the whole application was shutdown.

```
if(FULL_URL !== rtrim(PROTOCOL.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'/'){
    // Get path extension
    $ext = pathinfo(FULL_URL, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($ext !== ''){
        die;
    }
}
```

What can I do to determine if the http request is a broken file request or a normal request?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my problem by listening the field `Accept` given by the function `getallheaders()`:

```
if(FULL_URL !== rtrim(PROTOCOL.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'/'){
    // Get path extension
    $ext = pathinfo(FULL_URL, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($ext !== ''){

        $contenttype = isset(getallheaders()['Accept']) ? getallheaders()['Accept'] : NULL;

        if(empty($contenttype) || strpos($contenttype, 'text/html') === FALSE){
            die;
        }

    }
}
```